# is there a java library for dealing with access control list?

Tags: java, acl

I come from PHP environment where several frameworks introduces ACL classes, should I just use plain sets/maps or something and iterate or is there some type library for ACL in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html

"We provide a comprehensive ACL package with features including integer bit masking, permission inheritance (including blocking), an optimized JDBC-backed ACL repository, caching and a pluggable, interface-driven design."